# Does it make sense to create cryptocurrency based totally on go programming language?

Tags: development, performance

The question is straightforward. Would such implementation be practical from performance prespective? or C/C++ and JAVA are the gold standart?

Comment: Is this question about creating new cryptocurrency?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how well it performs, but here is a full node implementation of Bitcoin in go-lang that you could investigate: https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd